# Hash first column of each line in a text file and write this to the third column of the file

Tags: awk, sed, replace, hash

I have a file with the following format:

```
Value1 = Value1 <Value1>
Value2 = Value2 <Value2>
value3 = Value3 <Value3>
```

I want to write a script that will take each the first `Value` field in each line as input and calculate a hash of it, then write it to the corresponding fields on the right side of the `=` sign. All my input values are clear text.

so that i end up with something like this:

```
Value1 = 7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC <7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC>
Value2 = 0FE13ED1638DA4D4B1EF316729F3BB32 <0FE13ED1638DA4D4B1EF316729F3BB32>
Value3 = 121BCEF76AA7694F7D8EF4D381B86DAD <121BCEF76AA7694F7D8EF4D381B86DAD>
```

So far with the help below i have used:

```
awk '{cmd=sprintf("echo -n \"%s\"|md5sum",$3); 
   cmd|getline $3;close(cmd)}7' file
```

which writes the following to my output file:

```
Value1 = 7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC - <value1>
```

This is almost the complete solution but i need the hash to be copied to the value field between the "<>" characters as well as before them (this is an email address field but i can replace it with the username hash in my case). I also need the "-" character that seems to be written between the fields to be removed.

How can i get this to work perfectly?

Thanks

Comment: What's the algorithm of the Hash you wanted? And what have you tried?

Comment: either SHA or MD5 will do. I've tried using awk to go through each line and print the first column but i don't know how to write it to the second column

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55125276/edit) your question to add these details. Show your efforts, what you have tried and failed.

Comment: I've now edited to add extra details and discuss the progress from the solutions below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
awk '{cmd="echo -n " $3 " | md5sum"; if( (cmd | getline md5) > 0 ) {close(cmd);sub(/ .*/,"",md5);md5=toupper(md5)};$3=md5;$4="<" md5 ">";}1' file
Value1 = 7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC <7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC>
Value2 = 0FE13ED1638DA4D4B1EF316729F3BB32 <0FE13ED1638DA4D4B1EF316729F3BB32>
value3 = 121BCEF76AA7694F7D8EF4D381B86DAD <121BCEF76AA7694F7D8EF4D381B86DAD>
```

Given that the values inside and outside `<>` are guaranteed the same...

And if you have `ruby` installed, here's an ugly but probably more efficient way:

```
ruby -rdigest -lane 'md5=Digest::MD5.hexdigest($F[2]).upcase;$F[2]=md5;$F[3]="<" + md5 + ">"; print $F.join " "' file
```

Answer (score 0):

assume you would do a md5 hash, this gawk one-liner give you a start:

```
awk '{cmd=sprintf("echo -n \"%s\"|md5sum",$3);
         cmd|getline $3;close(cmd)}7' file
```

Comment: This works, Thanks! Is there anyway i can extend it to copy the hash an additional last column (containing emails currently) i haven't mentioned?  so i would have Value1=7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC <7EE5A281B28D7CA1FAB06B43D0B7D8AC>

Comment: it also seems to write a trailing "-" character. This may be because of the last field i previously forgot to mention. i've edited the question to better show what i mean.

Comment: @combatrock I think the awk line is pretty straightforward, can you try changing something by yourself? there are 100 ways to remove the last `-` also you can concatenate string `"<"hash">"` to overwrite the last field. just try something.